# How to Select the lowest record but not the lowest

Tags: sql, select

Records in database:

```
1
5
6
7
8
10

$select_query = "SELECT * FROM  images_tbl where images_id = $NextID ORDER BY images_id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

so if $NextID is 10 the next lowest record should be 8 not 1

Comment: If you include your DB when you post we can provide more meaningful answers.

Comment: You should specify the RDBMS what are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM  images_tbl ORDER BY images_id ASC LIMIT 1,1";
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't want the one = to $nextID, you want the next one "down".

```
$select_query = "SELECT Top 1 * FROM  images_tbl where images_id < $NextID ORDER BY images_id DESC
```

Comment: I think you want < $NextID, as this will pick the highest value in the table which does not match $NextID. You also need to put a * in there, as currently you're not selecting any fields.